# background won't resize vertically

Tags: css, background-image, image-resizing

I'm trying to make a website and I want an image (1920 × 1080) to cover the whole page. I used:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
```

And it looks fine. But when I resize my browser and pull it down vertically, the image does not come with it. I want my picture to resize for example like this site: https://www.okainsbayseafood.co.nz/ (when you resize the browser vertically the image goes with it)

Sorry for my English and if I sound stupid

[my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HNwj.jpg)

Comment: you need to make it responsive for every screen size. for that you need to learn bootstrap or any other responsive framework.

Comment: thank you. do you think its hard for a beginner to learn that?

Answer (score 2):

Switch `background-size` from `100%` to `cover`:

```
background-size: cover;
```

This tells the browser that the image should fill the available space, and will alter the dimensions of the image to do so.

**Note:** If you are adding this CSS to an element that is *not* the `body` tag, you may need to add additional code to resize the element to which you are adding this background. This CSS will create the desired effect if added directly to the `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have many possibilities to get such a result:

The page you linked above uses so called breakpoints, where it loads a resized image based on the screen size. This is indeed a good idea in that case, because they use very large images, which would load forever on small screens and low bandwidth.

For you, as a beginner, it is probably better to firstly get some deeper knowledge into CSS and what you can do with just a single image, and after that you can opt in to optimisations like the site above. So for you something like that would probably work:

```
background-image: url("yourimage.jpg");
background-color: #cccccc; /* Used if the image can not be loaded */
height: 100vh; /* You must set a height. (unless you have child elements that take the entire space) */
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
```

Study that CSS code and make sure you understand what it does and what other options you have. You might play around with some values there and get some other results.